# What does SOAPAction in Fiddler denote?

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx, fiddler

This is how my web request looks in Fiddler 2:

```
POST /TestService/WS/V1/ProviderService.asmx HTTP/1.1
```

In the SOAPAction value under Miscellaneous is : `http://TestService/V1/ListConstants`

`ListConstants` is the web method of in the `ProviderService`

If you observer the SOAPAction has the `WS` missing from the value which is there in the request header?

What is this SOAPAction in Fiddler? What is its significance? Why would `WS` be missing in the SOAPAction?

I am getting 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse' exception on this request.

Comment: What is it that you are observing in Fiddler? A client calling your service? What sort of client?

Comment: @John: Client is the winform application which is calling the ASMX web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SOAP 1.1, the SOAPAction header is used to select the operation to be called. If you look in the WSDL, you should see this specified for each operation.